# calculating the pseudoinverse with PARI/GP

Tags: linear-algebra, pari

How can I calculate the pseudoinverse for an arbitary mxn-
 matrix in PARI/GP ? Is there a simple way, or do I have to
 program the process completely ?

Answer (score 1):

Jörg Arndt has written code for the (Moore-Penrose) pseudoinverse here:

http://www.jjj.de/pari/

where it appears under `matsvd.gpi`.

In the simple (but common) case where the matrix has full column rank, you can compute it as

```
pseudoinverse(M) = my(ct=conj(M)~); (ct*M)^-1 * ct;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse?

[The tutorial and the manual for Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/doc.html) do not mention pseudoinverse, so you'll probably have to code your own solution.

The [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Construction) may help.You could also find algorithms in good advanced Linear Algebra books, as for example Jonathan Golan's [The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/The_Linear_Algebra_a_Beginning_Graduate.html?id=wKnzF3h-aeMC&redir_esc=y).